# Is there any way to detect the application we are going to upload on playstore is compatible with my device or not

Tags: android, android-permissions

I uploaded the app on play store but after uploading it shows this app is not compatible with your device. I know it is related with some permissions i used in the app but Is there any way to detect that the app we are going to upload on playstore will not compatible with perticular device.

And how can i raise the ticket on playstore for the same issue.

Comment: When you upload an .apk it tells you what devices it supports before you publish

Answer (score 1):

When you upload an APK to the Play Store (note, you don't actually have to push it to production), there will be a list of devices your app supports.

To see this, select the "*APK*" tab on the left, then there will be a section titled "*Supported devices*", which has a link to "*See List*" - this will let you see which devices your app supports (says I support over 9000 devices).

If the device you expect is not there, you need to make changes to your app (in the manifest), and not open a case with the Play Store (ie. it is something you need to fix, not them)

Answer (score 0):

It is not permission issue. There can be several reasons:
1) your app has in app purchises, and in your country they are not supported (linke in my contry)
2) maybe there are some features, that your device doesn't support, but your app uses, for example : call functionality and your app uses call function. 
Hope this helps